# Phonegapbuild hydration not working Android 8.1

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap, hydration

Recently hydration has ceased to work for my app. I had everything setup great a few weeks ago but upon resuming my project this week it has stopped working.

The app installs fine, detects an update, and downloads it. But then it gets stuck with the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL is not a function
>           at child.downloadComplete (hydra.js:219)
>           at child.trigger (backbone-min.js:163)
>           at hydra.js:200
>           at ContentSync.emit (plugins/phonegap-plugin-contentsync/www/index.js:171)
>           at success (plugins/phonegap-plugin-contentsync/www/index.js:98)
>           at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
>           at :1:9

I'm not quite sure what the issues is. Nothing has changed in my project but I have upgraded my device from 8.0 to 8.1.

I've tried including cordova-plugin-file as thats what appears to be missing. However, it didn't work. I assume that my projects plugins get loaded after hydration.